# Will Canada accept my passport near expiration date?

Tags: passports, canada

I am going to Canada from Minnesota, USA 7/11/20 and returning 7/18/20 to MN. My passport expires 8/16/20. Will Canada accept this passport?

Comment: While the passport should be okay as long as it's valid, do note that the US-Canada border is under heavy restrictions and could remain so until July or further. Even if the border reopens, federal and provincial authorities in Canada may still impose quarantine requirements. You should check these informations as your trip nears.

Answer (score 4):

Canada does not have the so-called 'six month rule' where passports must be valid six months beyond your stay. You can remain in Canada until the expiration date of your passport.

Comment: Canada doesn't require US citizens to have a passport to enter Canada, so it seems unlikely that a US citizen who entered Canada with a passport having less than six months' validity would be required to leave before the passport expires.